# How many twisted corners?

Tags: code-golf, array, rubiks-cube

Your challenge is to output the number of twisted corners given a 2x2 Rubik's Cube scramble.

For the purpose of this challenge, twisted corners are defined as corners where the colour of the top/bottom face before (usually white or yellow) is not facing the top/bottom after the scramble.
Eg. if the cube were to be oriented yellow top/white bottom, then the number of corners where yellow/white isn’t on the top/bottom after the scramble should be returned.

A scrambled cube is represented as a list of moves, where each move is denoted by the letters `UDRLFB` corresponding to clockwise turns of the faces: Up, Down, Right, Left, Front, and Back.
You have the option to replace the moves `UDRLFB` with a predefined set of constants. You may assume the scramble list is non-empty.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer wins!
Standard loopholes apply, [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14110) in particular is forbidden too.

### Test cases

[Example gif with scramble "L U U U F"](https://i.imgur.com/I3H6Nze.gif) | [Top and bottom face after scramble](https://i.imgur.com/psxC5pK.png)

```
[In]: R
[Out]: 4
[In]: L U U U F
[Out]: 3
[In]: R R D D D B B U L F
[Out]: 6
[In]: B U U D D F
[Out]: 0
```

Comment: ...not given it a tonne of thought but I think it's the same as for the 2x2 case too, right?

Comment: @JonathanAllan riight, I'll update the question

Comment: You should add a note that [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14110/92727) in particular is forbidden, since you allow choosing any set of constants

Comment: @close-voters What exactly isn't clear/needs more detail? Please leave a comment rather than just close voting so that the challenge can be improved.

Comment: Is `LLRR`(flip it upside down) 0 or 8? EDIT: Covered by last test case

Comment: @mathscat I hope my answer is acceptable, but do let me know if not!

Comment: What is the output of the input `R L L L`?

Comment: @Fmbalbuena `R` makes all the corners on the right side _twisted_ and `LLL` does the same to the left side (as it is just an anticlockwise quarter turn of the left face), so all eight corners end up _twisted_.

Comment: @JonathanAllan oh, missed the comment, yes, it’s totally fine! Nice answer btw

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 67 bytes

```
≔Ｅχ⁰θＦＥＳ⌕DBRUFLι«≔Ｉ⪪§⪪”)⧴∧\ⅈNυSＢ⊞ae”⁴ι¹ηＵＭθ⎇№ηλ﹪⁻ι§θ§η⊖⌕ηλ³κ»Ｉ№Ｘ⁰θ⁰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RZDbaoQwEIav16cIXk0gBY/rRa9WRVhYYXG7DxA0XUM10Rh7oPTZ7ehuaWBCDv/838zULTe15t2yHKZJ3hSUfADfY8SjjIz02XnVhmyPRzXM9mKNVDfAv0KqBtw8ra7FyWVEUkrJt7N7uGR8snAZOmnhYI@qEZ@PmxuEyT7aJ7EfJ6EXxb7nh4EX7CP0iOjqw4hPcWuRvUNupvueI2pk5EUYxc0XZHpWFlpGOtSVupk7DaVU8wSSkT/c@H9EZS5qI3qhrGhgq3zLXhcjIcYbRdyPc8bu7L34O@SsP4QBbx3FOhJULUtV5XmeptdTsTy9d78) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes a string of `DBRUFL` as input. Explanation:

```
≔Ｅχ⁰θ
```

Start with an array of zeros representing the untwisted corners. (There are ten rather than eight to save a byte.)

```
ＦＥＳ⌕DBRUFLι«
```

Map the input string into the integers `0-5` and loop over them. (The mapping is contrived to make the calculation below shorter, which is why I didn't require that as the input format.)

```
≔Ｉ⪪§⪪”)⧴∧\ⅈNυSＢ⊞ae”⁴ι¹η
```

Look up the corner permutation for this move, which is a list of indices of the corners that move in clockwise order.

```
ＵＭθ⎇№ηλ﹪⁻ι§θ§η⊖⌕ηλ³κ
```

For those corners that move, find the corner that moves to this corner, and subtract its value from the move index, modulo `3`.

```
»Ｉ№Ｘ⁰θ⁰
```

Output the final number of twisted corners.

22 bytes if I abuse the input format:

```
≔Ｅ⁸ιθＦＡＵＭθ§⮌↨ιφκＩ№÷θχ⁰
```

Takes input as an array of integers which represent a mapping to apply to the positions of the eight white and yellow stickers. No TIO link because I haven't actually bothered to compute suitable integers.

Comment: ooh nice approach!

Comment: @mathscat I only wish I could have come up with a formula for which corners are cycled for a given move.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>13</s>  12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Pushes the I/O rules to the edge ([confirmed that it is acceptable](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266733/how-many-twisted-corners?noredirect=1#comment581495_266733))</sup>

```
œ?@ƒ24s3I§ḂS
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of permutation indices of the 24 showing *facelets** and yields the number of *twisted corners*.

<sup>* i.e. the stickers on older cubes.</sup>

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcwrCgJRGEDhvQzYbvjfj6RJEASD3CRGi0wzWS0Gmy7CLQg2RfcxK7mO6ZSPs9/1/bG1z206@15JDrx43YfHad1WE8ThedkEQiRAEoQDC2OyAWDhVHRjwqIkJsEIqEnkWchhrLkjpTkFOTJHSmE3YPzvTJJUbfQggQUKq6ari6WGgqJA4PZ9bq1b1lrn3Q8)** (The footer converts the usual characters to the defined constants.)

#### How?

We label the eight corners using the three faces to which they belong in some arbitrary order, starting each with their U/D face and reading anticlockwise (again an arbitrary choice):

```
    UFR  URB  UBL  ULF  DRF  DBR  DLB  DBR
```

Now we label these stickers when in a solved state:

```
    ABC  DEF  GHI  JKL  MNO  PQR  STU  VWX
```

Now we record the six face-turn permutations:

```
D:  ABC  DEF  GHI  JKL  VWX  MNO  PQR  STU
L:  ABC  DEF  UST  HIG  MNO  PQR  WXV  LJK
B:  ABC  RPQ  EFD  JKL  MNO  TUS  IGH  VWX
U:  DEF  GHI  JKL  ABC  MNO  PQR  STU  VWX
F:  KLJ  DEF  GHI  XVW  CAB  PQR  STU  NOM
R:  OMN  BCA  GHI  JKL  QRP  FDE  STU  VWX
```

Now we find the index of each of these in all permutations of the solved state labelling by using code that I wrote that was added to [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/blob/70c9fd93ab009c05dc396f8cc091f72b212fb188/jelly/interpreter.py#L823) many moons ago (along with its family including `œ?`, see below) - [TIO](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5EP7HzWt@f//f7SSo5Ozi6ubu4enl7dPWHiEr59/QGBQcEiokg6XAlQyNDjEw9MdIhMeEebj5Q2TDAoIdHVzAeoESoaEBnu6ewCNAEvCzQSqgpsJk/T28YLIR4SFOzs6QST9/H3Bkv6@fk7OjhDNgUEBbi6ucJ2x/1Gci2IuAA):

```
D:                395176321
U:         5246483101592279
B:     35597574695850514081
F:  81089009208703431936001
U: 270227677129672827133894
R: 376031890064925569220481
```

Now with a list of these constants as our input, we can perform the permutations in turn and find the number of *twisted corners*:

```
œ?@ƒ24s3I§ḂS - Link: list of the defined constants, Scramble
    24       - twenty four
   ƒ         - start with State=24 and reduce using Scramble's Constants:
  @          -   with swapped arguments:
œ?           -     permutation at index {Constant} of the items in {State}
                     (when State=24 it's implicitly cast to [1..24])
      s3     - slice into threes (first of every triple is the U/D facelet)
                 (when Scramble="" the 24 we have is cast to [1..24] giving
                  us [[1,2,3],...,[22,23,34]])
        I    - forward differences of each
         §   - sums
          Ḃ  - modulo two
           S - sum
```

Comment: @downvoter - I assume this downvote came because of the choice of constants. Please note that I have asked OP about this [in a comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/266733/how-many-twisted-corners#comment581400_266733).